# Ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z} \to\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: number-theory

If m ∈ $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and n = 12 for what values of m is the function defined $\phi_m = \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_n, x\to(mx)\mod n$, a ring homomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : If $\phi_m$ is a homomorphism distinct of $0$ map then $\phi_m(1) = 1$